# Flutter flavor for iOS gives SharedPreference error on run

Tags: ios, flutter

Issue faced while trying to run flavors for iOS using Build Schemas

```
 /Labs/Workspace/Flutter/camp-flutter/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error:
    'shared_preferences/SharedPreferencesPlugin.h' file not found
    #import <shared_preferences/SharedPreferencesPlugin.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
```

### Flutter Doctor output

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

### Additional Information

We are using flavors and schemes for iOS build and using below command to run applications

```
flutter run --flavor abcd --target lib/main/abcd_main.dart
```

Comment: Can you run flutter run with verbose to see if it gives any additional error information. `flutter run --flavor abcd --target lib/main/abcd_main.dart --verbose`

Answer (score 0):

Uh, given that we can run build flavors via the changes from flutter 1.2 to 1.5 would not that be easier?

You use a build delegate your build config will use a new target flag that points to your new build flavor via dart file..see my medium post and several others talking about ti on medium...

[BuildExtensions](https://medium.com/@fredgrott/build-extensions-for-flutter-43dd5f0ee955)

The only hiccup is once in a while you have to wipe the emulator or device due to it having the old build flavor but generally it works

Comment: Fred, this isn't an issue, we can create dart level configs easily but the problem statement is with iOS Schemas that helps to develop different products by bundle id

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the debug and release build and there is some rules for this workaround:

folder to add .h file
debugging on simulator => `ios/Debug-iphonesimulator`
debugging on iOS => 'ios/Debug-iphoneos'
release on iOS => 'ios/Release-iphoneos'

BTW, I can build my project in all modes with many 3rd lib using this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this problem can be resolved in two ways. They are below.

I checked in one of my project and found SharedPreferencesPlugin.h has following code.

```
// Copyright 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>

@interface FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin : NSObject <FlutterPlugin>
@end
```

This file is present at location : 
[image: .h file's location]
(mysiyaram is the project name)

Now you might have two ways to solve this issue.
Plan A : You create the file manually with the code above. It doesn't contain any version specific info any way.

Plan B : Create another dummy project, add shared preferences in there. And copy the file (or folder structure) from the dummy project to your project.

**Note : Please take this options as a workaround since I don't know the structural solution.**

Comment: Didn't actually worked out this way. What I am seeking is a solution for managing Build Schema in iOS