# How to resolve missing required file for Flutter iOS Build

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

I have written my first non-trivial flutter app and have successfully built and run it on both the Android and iOS simulators and an Android device (MOTO G7). In attempting to build it for an Xs Max connected to my iMac I get the following error during the Xcode build:

```
/Users/dev/FirstApp/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: 'path_provider/PathProviderPlugin.h' file not found
```

I have searched the disk and found the following:

```
/Users/dev/FirstApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/path_provider/path_provider.framework/Headers/PathProviderPlugin.h
/Users/dev/FirstApp/build/path_provider/intermediates/javac/debug/compileDebugJavaWithJavac/classes/io/flutter/plugins/pathprovider/PathProviderPlugin.class
```

I have googled and checked SO for various hints/solutions. None of the, few, suggested fixes has worked for me. My Flutter Doctor -v command display all checkmarks and no issues.

Am I missing something? Is this a Flutter/Xcode bug? I am using Xcode 10.3 and Flutter 1.7.x. Any suggestions or outright fixes would be appreciated.

Comment: It's most likely to be a bug.

Comment: Try running `flutter clean build`

Comment: If it still doesn't resolve then put up the this issue on GitHub

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: "flutter clean build" did not help

Comment: Let this question be over here. Just ask this question on GitHib

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387094/1367159) answer.

Comment: Posting it on GitHub or not is entirely upto you.

Answer (score 0):

In your xcode Open the ***.xcworkspace** file instead of *.xcodeproj file then

1. Product>Clean
2. Product>Archive

and waiting